# Concatenating SQL results into single field (sql compact)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm currently trying to run the following query in SQL CE:

`select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name=[tablename]`

This query, as expected, returns a set of columns which belong to the specified table. The returned data looks like this:

```
column1
column2
column3
column4
```

However, for this particular scenario, it is very important that the results are returned as a single string in a single field.

My desired output is:

`column1,column2,column3,column4` etc...

How can I achieve this in SQL CE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine multiple results in a subquery into a single comma-separated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value)

Comment: @lc. does that solution work in CE?

Comment: @Ic. Please read both questions before claiming a duplicate. The link you posted is a SQL server question, this question is a SQL compact question.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830905/how-can-i-get-individual-results-in-sql-server-ce

Comment: @WawrzyniecSz. Again, please read both questions before linking a similar/duplicate question. The questions are completely different.